# How to disable left swipe gesture in react-native-gesture-handler/Swipeable?

Tags: react-native

**Description:**

We are creating a component similar like **Instagram** where we have a Posts screen and Messaging screen. When perform swipe from right to left, screen navigates from Posts screen to Messaging screen.
For swiping, we are using `@react-navigation/material-top-tabs`

In Messaging screen, Flatlist component is used to show conversations list where `react-native-gesture-handler/Swipeable` is used to show controls which are delete and mute button when user performs "right to left" swipe similar like Instagram which is working 100% fine but when trying to navigating back to post screen using left to right swipe on Flatlist then `react-native-gesture-handler/Swipeable` gesture executes and their "onSwipeableOpen" callback calls which should not execute so that smoothly translation should be perform from Messaging to Post Screen.

As well as there is no way to disable left to right swipe on FlatList. Is there any solution/ workaround or any suggestion to achieve this task?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can disable left swipe by using `dragOffsetFromLeftEdge`

```
 <Swipeable
    ...
    dragOffsetFromLeftEdge={Number.MAX_VALUE} 
  >
```

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to detect Left swipe and right swipe in `onSwipeableOpen`

```
//onSwipeableOpen?: (direction: 'left' | 'right') => void;

onSwipeableOpen(direction){
    //check direction here
    if(direction == 'left') return

    //do your operations
}
```

> And if you don't pass renderLeftActions to Swipeable then it will be disabled for Left Swipe.

Comment: I already did it but the requirement is to disable left swipe. Only right swipe should work. 
This is why because when we try to swipe back to Posts screen then `onSwipeableOpen` method executes and takes 1-2 seconds to executes which is not acceptable.
Any approach to disable Left swipe?

Answer (score -1):

Coming here because I was looking to solve a similar problem. The issue here is that FlatList is intercepting the "swipe to go back" gesture, you can mitigate it by giving the FlatList a left margin:

```
<FlatList contentContainerStyle={{ marginLeft: 15 }} ... />
```